# DataTable's Default View is different from Actual Table Data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using a huge datatable for a survey analysis. Instead of calling SQL server frequently am using row filtering on this datatable using DataView.

But the problem is once I filter the DataTable by

```
dv= dt.defaultview
dv.rowfilter="id=10"
```

that works fine. Dv having a filtered rows

But when we assign the same dt to another view, the Main datatables Default view being changed based on the filteration done for DV which is ID=10

So in the immediate window I checked this

```
dt.defaultview.totable().rows.count
```

and its 20 (WHich was because of the filteration done for DV)

but

```
dt.rows.count
```

is 1500 which is the correct count.

But my question is how this happened since I didnt touched the Datatable and I assigned the filter for DV only. Even then how the defaultview of the datatable changed?

Comment: I'm not with you. You are changing the tables's `DefaultView` by modifying it's `RowFilter` property. How are you "assigning the same `DataTable` to another view"? _"Even then how the defaultview of the datatable changed?"_ Isn't that obvious if you look at the first two lines of code you have posted?

Comment: Sorry.. Am not sure about this because am assigning that filter to a new dataview. So how the real defaultview gonna change?
dim dv as new dataview
dv=dt.defaultview
............

Comment: Well if you run `dv=dt.defaultview` then `dv` is the `DefaultView` of `dt`.

Comment: If you want to remove that filter on the `DefaultView` you have to assign empty string or `Nothing`: `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = ""`.

Comment: @DominicKexel OK.. I thought its only a replica when we assign that to DV.. If So let me try Tims method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Even then how the defaultview of the datatable changed?"* Isn't that obvious if you look at the first two lines of code you have posted?

```
dv = dt.DefaultView
dv.rowfilter = "id=10"
```

If you want to remove that filter on the `DefaultView` you have to assign empty `string` or `Nothing`:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = ""
```